# Conditionally lookup values in another dataframe to fill column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reference, lookup

I have one dataframe `df1` with the columns `age` and `testScore`. I need a third `normScore` based on `age`, `testScore` and references on a second dataframe `df2`. Let me show you:

`df1`

| age | testScore | normScore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78.6 | 1 |  |
| 87.1 | 2 |  |

`df2`

| ageStart | ageEnd | testScore | normScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 79.9 | 1 | 15 |
| 70 | 79.9 | 2 | 20 |
| 80 | 89.9 | 1 | 18 |
| 80 | 89.9 | 2 | 24 |

So what I need is to compare `age` in `df1` to `ageStart` and `ageEnd` in `df2` and then use `testScore` in `df1` to select `normScore` in `df2` and save `normScore` in `normScore` column in `df1`, like as follows:

`df1`

| age | testScore | normScore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78.6 | 1 | 15 |
| 87.1 | 2 | 24 |

On Excel I would use SUMPRODUCT, but I`m kinda new to R. Can you help me?
(I'm posting again because I messed up the tables in the previous post, sorry about that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting this [answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881) this could be achieved via the `fuzzyjoin` package like so:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  age = c(78.6, 87.1),
  testScore = c(1L, 2L)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  ageStart = c(70L, 70L, 80L, 80L),
  ageEnd = c(79.9, 79.9, 89.9, 89.9),
  testScore = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
  normScore = c(15L, 20L, 18L, 24L)
)

fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("testScore", "age" = "ageStart", "age" = "ageEnd"), match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)) %>%
  select(age, testScore = testScore.x, normScore)
#>    age testScore normScore
#> 1 78.6         1        15
#> 2 87.1         2        24
```